# PHP form email exception redirect to specific page

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect

I have a PHP form script that redirects to **example.com/page1** after submission, what I am trying to do is put an Email Exception so that

> ```
> if (userEmail = john@domain.com the script redirects to **example.com/page2** )
>
> else (redirects to **example.com/page1**)
> ```

so that ONLY john's email redirects to page2 and everyone get redirected to page1.

This is my current script code, I am not sure how I can put an exception for John's email.

```
$ssEmail = getVar($_REQUEST["ssEmail"]);

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
          {
              if($ssCopyEmail=='yes') { @mail($ssEmail, $subject, $message, $headers); }
               $sentMessage="Your Request has been submitted Successfully!";
               $rememberFields="no";

                ?>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
                <!-- 
                document.location = "https://example.com/page1";
                --> 
                </script>
                <?php

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your email template is same for all the user then, after executing email code, then you can redirect the request to respective page

```
 //email sent

 if($to=="john@domain.com")
 {
    // redirect page2
 }
 else
 {
     // redirect page1
 }
```

In case, you have multiple list of email's then use `in_array`.

Comment: no, it's the same template sent to everyone, so where exactly should I put this if condition?

Comment: @JosephRaphael Once, you sent the email. Otherwise, you will be redirecting it without sending email.

Comment: ok so if I put it right after  $rememberFields="no"; will it work ?

Comment: @JosephRaphael I believe `@mail` used to sent mail. If yes, then my answer is also `Yes`.